# PHP mysql array_diff doesn't match all the fields

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Old fields (cutoff)

```
| exceptions    |
+---------------+
| ryu,moderator |
```

New fields (accounts)

```
| username      |
+---------------+
| ben           |
+---------------+
| moderator     |
+---------------+
| john          |
+---------------+
| james         |
+---------------+
| ryu           |
```

I want to remove the duplicated fields but the code below didn't work (sample)

```
$expr_old = explode(',', $exceptions);
$expr_new = explode(',', $newfields);

echo implode(array_diff($expr_new, $expr_old), ',');
```

The full code

```
$query = "SELECT ACC.username AS username, SAL.income AS income, CDIR.exceptions AS except ";
$query .= "FROM accounts ACC ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN info INF ON ACC.user_id = INF.iuid ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN sales SAL ON ACC.user_id = SAL.suid ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN cutoff_direct CDIR ON ACC.username = CDIR.user";

$s = $sqlConnection->query($query);

while ($row = $s->fetch_assoc())
{
    $ss = $sqlConnection->query("SELECT username FROM accounts WHERE sponsor = '$row[username]'");

    $exceptions = '';

    while ($rrow = $ss->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $exceptions .= $rrow['username'] . ',';
    }

    $expr_old = explode(',', $row['except']);
    $expr_new = explode(',', $exceptions);

    echo implode(array_diff($expr_new, $expr_old), ',');
}
```

Output: the username `ryu` remains

My problem is that some duplicate users appears unexpectedly.

Comment: are you sure you don't have any character (e.g. space) at the end of `$newfields`?

Comment: parameters to implode are wrong `implode ($glue, $array)`

Comment: This will remove the duplicates: array_unique( array_merge($expr_old, $expr_new) ); Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: `array_unique( array_merge($expr_old, $expr_new));`, still `ryu` and `moderator` remain

Answer (score 2):

I executed the following code and the output was as expected.

```
$exceptions = 'ryu,moderator';
$newfields = 'ben,moderator,john,james,ryu';
$expr_old = explode(',', $exceptions);
$expr_new = explode(',', $newfields);
echo implode(array_diff($expr_new, $expr_old),',');
```

Output :-

```
ben,john,james
```

Do check that the strings you are exploding do not contain any spaces. Words should be separated only by commas.

Comment: I think the problem is probably on this line `$exceptions .= $rrow['username'] . ',';` because it'll add comma at the end.

Comment: No, given the extra comma at the end of $exceptions string, the output remains same.

Comment: The parameters to implode are fine. Try echoing the $exceptions string. Check its value at the end of your loop.